# import statsmodels package returns ModuleNotFound despite correct path

Tags: importerror, statsmodels

I am trying to import  [statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.tconfint_mean](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.tconfint_mean.html).

I run

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW import tconfint_mean
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
'statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW';
'statsmodels.stats.weightstats' is not a package
```

I have confirmed that I can import other packages from statsmodels with no problems.

I must be using the wrong path, but the docs don't specify any other path to use.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. I will leave this up for progeny.

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW

DescrStatsW.tconfint_mean(...)
```

Not sure why this behaves differently from other python libraries.